# Overwriting a WooCommerce php file in a child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm attempting to modify the WooCommerce products page (in the admin area), essentially I just need to add a Brands column to the table. The correct method of doing this is to use a child theme. However how can I overwrite only a specific page from WooCommerce? I have an existing child theme setup, so simply copying the entire WooCommerce functions.php file is out of the question.

Thanks

Comment: you want to customize product detail page or product list page?

Comment: The product details page in the admin area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at adding a custom column to Woocommerce product page. You don't have to use a child theme for this purpose. You'll have to use the `manage_edit-product_columns` filter to add the column and the `manage_product_posts_custom_column` action to control what is displayed in the column.

Find the relevant Codex links below.

1. [manage_${post_type}_posts_columns](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns)
2. [manage_{post_type}_posts_custom_column](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column)